# Error registering plugin in Nuxt, recursive component?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am struggling to add this https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-grid to my nuxt plugins!

In `nuxt.config.js` I have:

```
plugins: [
  { src: '~/plugins/vue-js-grid.js', ssr: false }
],
```

in `vue-js-grid.js` I have:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Grid from 'vue-js-grid'

Vue.use(Grid)
```

in `mytemplate.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <no-ssr>
      <Grid
        :draggable="true"
        :sortable="true"
        :items="items"
        :height="100"
        :width="150">
        <template slot="cell" slot-scope="props">
          <div>{{props.item}}</div>
        </template>
      </Grid>
    </no-ssr>
  </div>
</template>
```

(their example code)
but I receive this error:

```
commons.app.js:11507 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <Grid> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Pages/mytemplate.vue> at pages/mytemplate.vue
       <Nuxt>
         <Default> at layouts/default.vue
           <Root>
```

As far as I can tell, I’ve registered everything correctly? Is this not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to write `grid` in lower case in your template?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <no-ssr>
      <grid
        :draggable="true"
        :sortable="true"
        :items="items"
        :height="100"
        :width="150">
        <template slot="cell" slot-scope="props">
          <div>{{props.item}}</div>
        </template>
      </grid>
    </no-ssr>
  </div>
</template>
```

Also, after registering your plugin, did you restart your development server?

Comment: thanks! I didn’t realise it was necessary to restart the dev server. I did a quick search on this but can’t find anything – what is the reasoning?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that this is because the `nuxt.config.js` file is loaded once when server starts

Comment: After a lot of trial and error I found this. Restarting the nuxt dev server worked for me too.